# How to update 12k records in 1 minute in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, data-science, background-process

I'm using Django(3.2.11) with the Postgres database. and we have 12k stocks symbols stored in a database. now we are updating their price in the database frequently with `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{symbols}/intraday-prices?token={iex_api_key}&chartIEXOnly=true`.
now I am required to update all 12k stock prices in 1 minute. for now, I'm using the celery periodic task. but the task took more than 1 minute for completing.
so how to update all stocks in 1 minute

Comment: provide your models and how you're going to filter your each object ?

Comment: Try this [bulk_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

Comment: Django is convenient, but it is adding a layer of overhead.  You might consider doing a bulk SQL update directly.

Comment: i have to call one by one this API `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{symbols}/intraday-prices?token={iex_api_key}&chartIEXOnly=true` for get stock's symbol price every minute